# How to correct Django server from loading basic html on web browser instead of standard html?

Tags: django, static-files

How can I correct the basic html display I get when I load the Django admin page, just as shown in the snapshot attached?

[image]

Comment: Django doesn't find the static files. There are a lot of similar questions with answers already, please have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=django+admin+static. Please have a look at my edit too and try to write your questions properly next time. hth

Answer (score 0):

This is because your static files aren't set up properly. Typically Django's development `runserver` will take care of this for you, but in production, you need to run `python manage.py collectstatic` after ensuring your static files settings are correct: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files

Good luck!